# Input elements are displayed the whole width of the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap to make input elements with prepended text, using code from

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#basic-example

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

The problem is that the inputs are wrongly displayed:

[image: wrong display]

This is how it should be displayed

[image: correct display]

I already deleted all the contents of my css file to test if the problem was there but it isn't.
I assume that can be fixed with css, but I don't know how.

Comment: It is working as expected...

Comment: https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/gOmxgNN

Comment: Thanks @deckp, I think the problem was that I had the boostrap link in a base template when I passed to the current template It work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to happen your classes are not calling the CSS anexed to them.

Comment: Yes thank you!!, Tha was exactly the problem I had, for some reason, another bootstrap link that was making the conflict, after been removed it worked